# Отслеживание нагрузки, создаваемой плагинами Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, производительность

Собираюсь на VPS поставить nginx, PHP 7 и Wordpress.

На эту CMS существует очень много различных плагинов и некоторые из них довольно криво написаны. Я понимаю, что погоня за каждой лишней милисекундой обычно глупая затея, но я недавно обнаружил, что плагин `Ultimate Addons for Visual Composer` создавал огромную нагрузку на CPU, вследствие чего админка грузилась в 6 раз дольше.

В общем, мне нужен способ отслеживать нагрузку на процессор и память (или относительную нагрузку в процентах) для каждого из установленных плагинов. Несколько лет назад я пользовался плагином `P3 Plugin Profiler`. Но он давно не обновляется, а также не поддерживает PHP 7. В настоящий момент не существует плагинов-альтернатив.

Есть ли какие-то расширения/модули для nginx или php, которые могут выполнить поставленную задачу? Я слышал про сервис New Relic, но цены там очень высокие.

Comment: Профилирование с помощью phpStorm + xDebug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Есть ли какие-то расширения/модули для nginx или php, которые могут
>   выполнить поставленную задачу?

xdebug, Kcachegrind и пр.
Плагины типа https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Также рекомендую посмотреть эти доклады разработчиков:
https://wordpress.tv/2015/08/20/konstantin-kovshenin-wordpress-performance-killers/
https://wordpress.tv/2016/10/08/konstantin-kovshenin-memory-devourers-in-wordpress/
https://wordpress.tv/2013/08/19/konstantin-kovshenin-wordpress-site-speed/
https://wordpress.tv/2014/08/25/gennady-kovshenin-profiling-wordpress/

Comment: Погоди, а query monitor только ведь MySQL запросы показывает. Никакого cpu и памяти там нет, насколько я помню.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, он много чего показывает, не только по базе.

Comment: список что показывает:https://i.imgur.com/mQH9LnY.jpg  общая инфа: https://i.imgur.com/Uk5HGSt.jpg ошибки php: https://i.imgur.com/eqqaU9J.jpg время функций https://i.imgur.com/1CxGQtv.jpg

Comment: Хорошие киношки прислал, я посмотрел с удовольствием.