# Больше время ttfb

Tags: wordpress

Сайт [mkosmetic](https://mkosmetic.com.ua) на WordPress. Проблема вот в чем: большое время ttfb. На главной странице оно мизирное, страница загружается нормально(относительно)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другие страницы медленнее грузит. Время ttfb бывает от 2 до 4 секунд, соответственно долго грузит страницы. Вот скрин. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плагины удалял, тему менял, результата особого не было. Плюс к этому около 140 запросов к базе данных которые генерируются около 2сек.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как быть?

Comment: См ссылки в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818850/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-wordpress/818902#818902 с комментами

Comment: 140 запросов к базе - это ни о чем. А 2 сек до 1 байта - ужасно. Скорее всего, сервер никуда не годится, или перегружен.

Comment: Зашёл на сайт, вроде быстро грузится. Никаких 2 секунд не увидел